# How does this teradata timestamp with timezone example make sense?

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

In the teradata documentation it says:

> "Suppose an installation is in the PST time zone and it is New Years Eve, 1998-12-31 20:30 local time.
>
> The system TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE for the indicated time is ' 1999-01-01 04:30-08:00 ' internally."

This does not mesh with my understanding. I figure it ought to be `'1999-01-01 04:30+00:00'` internally because it should be stored in UTC.
Or, it can be stored as a the local time with a `-8` offset, but this example seems to mix the two. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the text?

Comment: You need to read that whole section carefully, it's kind of funky.  `Timestamp with timezone` is relative to GMT.  That's exactly what it's giving you.

Comment: Yes I agree. its relative to GMT, but it should be '1998-12-31 20:30 -08:00' or '1999-01-01 04:30+00:00', NOT  ' 1999-01-01 04:30-08:00 ' . It seems to have mixed the timestamp (utc value) and the timezone (pst value) Could you please answer with more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is an answer, but it's too long for a comment.

That "internal" storage part is very misleading.  We don't care how Teradata stores anything internally.

I find this easier to look at using BTEQ, since SQL Assistant doesn't show timezones, at least by default. So, assuming you've logged into BTEQ...

```
    --set session timezone to pst (GMT - 8)
    SET TIME  ZONE INTERVAL -'08:00' HOUR TO MINUTE ;
    create volatile table vt_foo ( 
    ts_w_zone  timestamp(0) with time zone, 
    ts_wo_zone timestamp) on commit preserve rows;
    insert into vt_foo 
    select
    cast('1998-12-31 20:30:00' as timestamp(0)),
    cast('1998-12-31 20:30:00' as timestamp);
select * from vt_foo;
```

Currently the two values (with and without tz) will match.

```
                ts_w_zone                  ts_wo_zone
-------------------------  --------------------------
1998-12-31 20:30:00-08:00  1998-12-31 20:30:00.000000
```

Now let's change the timezone for your session to something else, and look at what we get.

```
SET TIME  ZONE INTERVAL -'03:00' HOUR TO MINUTE ;
select * from vt_foo;

                ts_w_zone                  ts_wo_zone
-------------------------  --------------------------
1998-12-31 20:30:00-08:00  1999-01-01 01:30:00.000000
```

The timestamp with zone is still the same.  Displaying it without timezone is automatically converting it to your session timezone, which in this example is GMT -3.

EDIT:
Technically, Teradata is actually storing the time with timezone as GMT (1999-01-01 04:30:00) with the timezone offset (-8).  That's where the documentation gets the  1999-01-01 04:30-08:00 value from).  But that is not how it displays it.

Comment: @adheebg, again, this is only the funky way Teradata **stores** the data. It is a combination of the time in GMT, and the offset of the timezone from the session when the data was inserted.

Comment: @Andrew: SQL Assistant show time zones when you switch to .NET (it's a known ODBC limitation)